# Native Typescript class in VueJS 3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am starting with VueJS 3 and would like to use Typescript classes this way:

main.js

```
import {AppConfiguration} from "@/lib/AppConfiguration.ts"

const appConfiguration = new AppConfiguration();
```

AppConfiguration.ts

```
export class AppConfiguration
{
    // classComponentMapping : [string[], string[]];

    constructor() {
        this.classComponentMapping =
            [['btn', 'ShowFeedbackFormBtn'],
            ['form', 'ProvideFeedbackForm']]
    }
}
```

No problem so far. But after enabling the property declaration in `AppConfiguration` I got this error:

```
 error  in ./src/lib/AppConfiguration.ts

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:26)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export class AppConfiguration
| {
>     classComponentMapping : [string[], string[]];
|
|     constructor() {

 @ ./src/main.js 11:0-61 18:27-43
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.2.26:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

My version of Webstorm is 2020.2. The projectsetup has been made with Webstorm. Node version is 14.7.6.
My babel config:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

Comment: What version of TypeScript is this? Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: Honestly speaking, there's no tsconfig.json at the root of the project. So, I've no idea which Typescript version is running. I started the project with File>New Project> Vue.js.

Comment: @tony19 what do you mean with a reproduction? Do you want a link to a Github repo?

Comment: A reproduction of the problem. Yes, a GitHub link would do.